# Deflod rendering issue

Tags: lua, defold

I am going to make simple 2D game in Defold game engine and I am new in this area. My question is, I have 2 game objects every object has sprites in it. A sprite in the first game object must be background for sprites of second object. I have designed it well but when I run (or render, I don't know how to call properly) it sometimes sprites of second game object are invisible and some times everything is OK.
[image: my design and when i run the game]

The same issue if I set main backgruon image for the game. Please share your experiences with me. Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You posted the same question on the [official Defold forum](https://forum.defold.com/t/defold-rendering-issue-solved/20701) so I'm going to replicate the answer you got there here on SO as well. The solution is to make sure that the depth of two game objects that overlap isn't the same. If two objects have the same depth and overlap you might sometimes see one in front of the other and sometimes vice versa. The default render script allows a z-range of -1 to 1 (you can use fractional z-values to get fine grained control), but you can copy it from builtins and increase the range if you want to. Something like -10 to 10 is usually a good enough value.

Comment: Thanks again, I posted it on the Defold forum after waiting an answer here.